# How to analyze and fix random failure due to CORS and Chrome using WSO2 API Manager 2.6.0

Tags: cors, wso2, wso2-api-manager

When creating URL pattern in API Publisher I created GET method **/something/v2%2E0** – as you can see I used encoding %2E instead of dot 2.0.

When testing it I noticed that the method works when I use FF but doesn‘t work on Chrome with the following error message:
 
*Access to fetch at 'https://something:port/context/v1.0/something/v2.0?limit=1' from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*

I checked the headers in both browsers and noticed the following difference: in response headers FF  had “Accept: * / *” and Chrome didn’t.

Changing CORS configurations did not help. Currently my CORS conf looks like this:
**Enable API based CORS Configuration:** yes
 
**Access Control Allow Origins:** yes - All Allow Origins
 
**Access Control Allow Headers:** authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type, SOAPAction, Authorization
 
**Access Control Allow Methods:** GET, OPTIONS

I installed and enabled Chrome plugin which enables Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * and still it didn‘t work.
 
 
The funny part is that the method started working only when I added additional GET method **/something/v2.0**. When this new method exists in API publisher, **/something/v2%2E0** starts working and I get “Accept: * / * “ in Chrome header. If I delete **/something/v2.0**, **/something/v2%2E0** doesn’t fetch data.

Any tips and hints appreciated :)

### Adding OPTIONS header (request and response) as requested in comments.

[image: request]

[image]

Comment: Can you record the OPTIONS call sent by the browser and post it here? request and response headers.

Comment: Added as requested.

Comment: Seems it's not working for encoded resources. Just having `/something/v2.0` only didn't work either?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use something/v2.0 only, because of the bug in API-M Publisher. If I create the method with a dot like v2.0, Publisher does not allow me to add parameters to this method. I believe it's just a bug in WSO2 Publisher. Therefore, I have to use %2E

Comment: Parameters are only required if you need to display them in Store's API console and exposed swagger. End users are not affected by not having parameter defined. So, maybe you can take that approach.

Comment: Thank you, Bee, I didn't know that.